# Why does a floating child element prevent the parent's padding from pushing elements inwards?

Tags: html, css, css-float, padding

[image: What I want] vs. what I have:

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
  padding-left: .75em;
}

p {
  padding-left: 1.50em;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 16em;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.formDiv {
  text-align: center;
}

#border {
  border: .25em solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#calculate,
#clear {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="salesTax.css">
    <title>Sales Tax Calculator</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="border">
        <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>
        <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p>
        <form>
          <div class="formDiv">
            <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
            <input type="text" id="subtotal">
          </div>
          <div class="formDiv">
            <label for="taxRate">Tax Rate:</label>
            <input type="text" id="taxRate">
          </div>
          <div class="formDiv">
            <label for="salesTax">Sales Tax:</label>
            <input type="text" id="salesTax" disabled>
          </div>
          <div class="formDiv">
            <label for="total">Total:</label>
            <input type="text" id="total" disabled>
          </div>
          <div class="formDiv">
            <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
            <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <script src="salesTax.js"></script>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

As far as I can tell, the `float: left` applied to the labels here is causing them to fill up as much of `#formDiv` as possible to get the labels to the left of the inputs.  Since I want the labels and inputs to be more centered, I thought I would apply padding to the `#border`, but all that does is expand it outward rather than pushing the inner elements inwards.

**Why is that?**  Is there anything I can do to prevent that **without removing any of the provided CSS?** *(The only CSS I can delete parts of is the CSS for `#border`.  The rest is part of the specification, but can be added onto.)*

Comment: `text-align:center` should do . an **id value** can be used only once BTW , use class instead for `formDiv`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Ugh, silly mistake from me trying out different things.  Yes, that should be a class.  `text-align: center` for that class doesn't change anything, though.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I also updated the original post — I had the wrong picture up there for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The only thing you can change is the rules for `#border`? Really? That seems unduly limiting; though real-world job-requirements are a thing, obviously. Or - and I hope this is the case - are you allowed to adjust the CSS so long as it all looks the same?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, it is pretty limiting.  To be clear, I **can** add things into each selector's CSS, I just can't remove the parts I was given.  I can also add totally new CSS (`#border` is something I added.)

Comment: So, you can't - as an example - change from `float` to using `flex`, or `grid`?

Comment: @DavidThomas Correct.  I tried adding `flex` and `grid` to the `.formDiv`s to get around this but that didn't seem to fix it.  Granted I'm not very experienced in CSS (the primary focus for this is the JS, which I didn't include here).  I'm just really confused why adding `padding-right` to the `#border` doesn't push the inputs and labels inwards.

Comment: Can you edit the HTML?

Comment: Regarding border question... The #border element is aligned with left side of container and it can grow horizontally, adding *right* padding will make it grow on the *right* side, the inner elements will maintain their position. When #border cannot grow then the inner elements will shrink or wrap onto next lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding cannot "push in" the contents that are already at the minimum width. `display: inline-block` causes `<div id="border">` to be no wider than its contents. Therefore, `padding-right` increases the width of `<div id="border">`.

The only way to "push in" the inner elements would be to reduce the width of those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, in your case, the use of a `<table>` will be appropriate:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#border {
  border: .25em solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

#border h1 {
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#border p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#border table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#border table td {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#border table td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="border">
    <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>
    <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p>
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="subtotal"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="taxRate">Tax Rate:</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="taxRate"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="salesTax">Sales Tax:</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="salesTax" disabled></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="total">Total:</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="total" disabled></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
            <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

**Update.** If you have a phobia of tables :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#border {
  border: .25em solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#border h1 {
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#border p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#border form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#border form label {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
  <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>
  <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p>
  <form>
    <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
    <input type="text" id="subtotal">
    <label for="taxRate">Tax Rate:</label>
    <input type="text" id="taxRate">
    <label for="salesTax">Sales Tax:</label>
    <input type="text" id="salesTax" disabled>
    <label for="total">Total:</label>
    <input type="text" id="total" disabled>
    <span></span>
    <span>
      <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
      <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be tabular data, so I'd argue - and this is, of course, only my opinion - that a `<table>` should not be used. Besides, if a `<table>` *is* used then it's a maintenance nightmare, as well as an obsolete, outdated, and historically deplorable practice to use tables for layout.

Comment: @DavidThomas  Dear, I do not see anything terrible in using a table in this case. But in general, your horror of tables does not make any sense. Maybe you just don't understand how they work? "maintenance nightmare", "outdated and historically deplorable practice" )) I'm not creating a page layout, but solving a small case in the context of this task. Perhaps you can offer a more elegant solution instead of putting a minus. I will be glad to see. Best regards.

Comment: the use of a table seems also appropriate to me , a list of numbers , th instead labels would be fine too . there is a caption , a summarry , a tbody and even a footer for the result ... not too sure where buttons should stand inside or outside the table ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thank you! According to the screenshot from the question, the buttons should be in the middle of the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add style via the `#border` selector, then you can easily overwrite other styles.

Possible example :

```
div#border {
  max-width: max-content;
  padding-right: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;/* or inline-grid */
  justify-content: center;
}

#border .formDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#border label {
  width: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

snippet to test render

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
  padding-left: .75em;
}

p {
  padding-left: 1.50em;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 16em;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.formDiv {
  text-align: center;
}

#border {
  border: .25em solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#calculate,
#clear {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
/* overwrite previous style if already defined */
div#border {
  max-width: max-content;
  padding-right: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;/* or inline-grid without max-width/padding/margin */
  justify-content: center;
}

#border .formDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#border label {
  width: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="salesTax.css">
  <title>Sales Tax Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="border">
      <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>
      <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p>
      <form>
        <div class="formDiv">
          <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
          <input type="text" id="subtotal">
        </div>
        <div class="formDiv">
          <label for="taxRate">Tax Rate:</label>
          <input type="text" id="taxRate">
        </div>
        <div class="formDiv">
          <label for="salesTax">Sales Tax:</label>
          <input type="text" id="salesTax" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="formDiv">
          <label for="total">Total:</label>
          <input type="text" id="total" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="formDiv">
          <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
          <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="salesTax.js"></script>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This looks pretty good.  The thing I'm still trying to find some understanding of is the first part of the question: why does `float: left` cause this effect where, for example, `#border { padding-right: 1em }`, pushes the border outwards rather than the elements (the contents of the `.formDiv`s) inwards?

Comment: This will only work if the `input` elements are the same width. Try changing the `input` type to a `checkbox` or a `file` and see what happens.

Comment: @imhvost you may also remove the label, add buttons and build a total different forms, of course it will messes up everything ;) - that is only  a possible example , not a universal way or magic fix ;)

Comment: @dylosaur float comes with sides effect that can be confusing. It won't stretch a parent, a sibbling will be drawn behind it but content will flow around it ...(  grid or flex took over to avoids this misuse of float )however, you also give a 16em width to the labels. -|- Sometimes you can allow yourself to use a table element which would be justified here ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus It's just that your solution is not universal. Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question properly, then adding:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

to the div that wraps the inputs (buttons) should achieve the result you're looking for:

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
  padding-left: .75em;
}

p {
  padding-left: 1.50em;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 16em;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

#border {
  border: .25em solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#calculate,
#clear {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="salesTax.css">
  <title>Sales Tax Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="border">
      <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>
      <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p>
      <form>
        <div id="formDiv">
          <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
          <input type="text" id="subtotal">
        </div>
        <div id="formDiv">
          <label for="taxRate">Tax Rate:</label>
          <input type="text" id="taxRate">
        </div>
        <div id="formDiv">
          <label for="salesTax">Sales Tax:</label>
          <input type="text" id="salesTax" disabled>
        </div>
        <div id="formDiv">
          <label for="total">Total:</label>
          <input type="text" id="total" disabled>
        </div>
        <div id="formDiv" class="btns">
          <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
          <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="salesTax.js"></script>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've edited the original post to switch `#formDiv` to `.formDiv` (stupid mistake from refactoring). However, while your solution (and `text-align: center`) do push the buttons into the right place, the inputs are stuck on the right edge of the border. I also had the wrong picture for what I want up there, so that's fixed, too.